# Why won't my laptop detect my VGA cable after start-up?

Tags: vga

I plug the VGA cable from my computer to the TV.  After that, I turn the computer on. The display is shown on the TV but once the Ubuntu login screen appears, my connection is then lost.

Are there any good suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather vague, so you'll more likely get more useful answers if you can provide more information. Here's some things to start with:

**What graphics card drivers are you using?** I've found that the generic drivers tend to not play well with multiple monitors. Make sure you pick up the good drivers for your graphics card. If you have an Nvidia card, or a newer ATI/AMD card, then you may need to tell Ubuntu to use the "non-free" software and install the proprietary drivers.

**Can you output to a standard monitor?** Does the same cable and port output successfully to a regular computer monitor? If not, the cable or the card might be bad. Swap out the cable and see if it works, then try the TV again.

**Does the graphics card support the TV's resolution? (Conversely, does the TV support the card's available resolutions?)** Graphics cards output only certain resolutions, and monitors (including TVs) only display at certain resolutions. Usually, the card will automatically match up the best fit. However, it will usually try to do that and maintain the monitor's aspect ratio and will fail if it doesn't find one, even if there's a match at a less than ideal aspect ratio. Check your display software (either the built-in "Display" system settings, or Nvidia's or ATI/AMD configuration manager) to see if it's actually detected but can't output at the resolution that it wants.

**Is the output turned on?** Sometimes, the computer won't detect the monitor until you tell it to connect (even though it outputs to the other monitor until login). Check your display settings and see if it does know that it's *there*, but doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: im using nvidia graphics card i dont know what else i can tell u about it. the same thing happens when i plug it in to a regular computer moniter. and where can u find the output setting at?

Comment: You're probably using the generic graphics drivers, then. Ubuntu should tell you in the notification area that there are proprietary drivers available (see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia ). Once those are installed, then you can change your display settings using the Nvidia settings manager, which you can find in the Activities/Applications menu.